# Really, what is love?

Tags: love

What do people mean when they say "love"?

Do they know what they are saying or has the English language messed up the meaning, ie it may not exist? How does it differ from “like”? Is it pure feeling or is it a mixture of a bunch of experiences?

Comment: This seems very broad and likely to encourage only opinion based answers. It may be closed for that reason. If you associate the question with something you are reading and ask for an explanation of that text it may make the question more specific. Welcome!

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy SE! Check out the [SEP article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/love/). It's a very nice and readable introduction to this area. Your "is it pure or a mixture?" question might be related to section 5 on love as an emotion vs emotion complex. There are other views of love discussed in the article too, that view love not as strictly an emotion.

Comment: [A: Baby, don't hurt me, don't hurt me, no more.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEXWRTEbj1I)

Comment: Five feet of heaven in a ponytail. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5-HHxwoa98

Answer (score 2):

You are right in detecting a linguistic problem and I certainly think our modern society would be many notches better if like the [ancient Greeks](https://www.yesmagazine.org/happiness/the-ancient-greeks-6-words-for-love-and-why-knowing-them-can-change-your-life) we nuanced love a bit more.

They had 6 words eros, philia, ludus, agape, pragma, philautia.

- Eros : sexual love "out of control" hormones
- Philia : genuine deep friendship
- Ludus : playful "men guffawing drunk"
- Agape : Universal love (Jesus, Mother Theresa type)
- Pragma : "Staying in love" (rather than falling) Think the (rare!) 80 year old happily marrieds
- Philautia : Self-love of the good sort, When you are deeply happy with yourself you have no need to run down or hurt others. Related to the [vedantic idea](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/61240/37256)
  of *atma* the ultimate unity of individual and universal self

Comment: I didn't realize they had so many words for love. Perhaps such answers can focus this question so it is not just opinion based.

Comment: It's not a *problem* to have a rich and nuanced polysemous word. Native speakers would not ever confuse the love someone has for the mother, their lover, or their favourite flavour of icecream.