# Neo-liberalism, language and freedom?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, political-philosophy, wittgenstein, metaethics, definitions

### Background

Byung Chulhan in his book [psychopolitics](https://youtu.be/ObCTx4UNwnA) defines freedom in two ways:

**a.** He defines it as an interlude which the subject feels when passing between lifestyles or ideologies. This is a somewhat cynical approach to defining liberty especially when we pay mind to the use of the term subject. Subject is often used when describing an individual or entity. That is in literal terms being subjugated or brought under control freedom in this sense is just the absence of the natural order of things of in: A rare moment not being subjected to a certain lifestyle. What if we remarketed and rebranded this word: age of neoliberalism has led to a shared belief that we are projects to be worked on rather than subjects to be dominated this process of projection however is really just a more efficient form of subjugation instead of any sort of all-powerful disciplinary instrument coercing us to be something we coerce and constrain ourselves to become what we think we want to be.

**b.** The second idea of freedom is a little bit more cheery. Freedom is to be among friends to have a successful relationship with others; it signifies a relationship as noted by the common root shared across indo-european languages between the words freedom and friendship.

This (b) may seem strange especially in capitalist societies where individual freedom is far more valued than this idea of self-realization through others. Psychopolitics is a thesis where Byung made sense of the word freedom.

Wittgenstien might say language is in some sense a community consensus. So can this word “freedom” be realized via consensus? If so, was freedom squandered? Chomsky successfully points out there is a human condition and biases in the very nature of language itself. Across different cultures the origins of the words friendship and freedom is striking indeed.

> "Philosophers, (the later) Wittgenstein believed, had been misled into
> thinking that their subject was a kind of science, a search for
> theoretical explanations of the things that puzzled them: the nature
> of meaning, truth, mind, time, justice, and so on. "

While he does not explicitly mention freedom I suspect he would have easily added it to the list.

Could Wittgenstien or anyone even define freedom? I suspect the answer would at best be a private language game. But at the age of 10 the word freedom may be a different private language game than it is at the age of 25. But then I suspect we fall into the trap of the first definition (point a) and perhaps the reader should again re-read from point a.

### Question

I find myself asking is it possible to coherently hold onto a set of insights?

1. There exists a notion of freedom
2. Wittgenstein - Language is a community consensus
3. Chomsky - Biases in humans and language exist
4. Our thoughts on various matters are informed by interactions with our community
5. (The opposite of) Byung Chulhan - Freedom and Neoliberalism are not at odds with each other

Comment: Neither "definition" is an honest attempt to get at what people mean by the word.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I suspect this is more of a symptom of me reducing a book into 2 paragraphs. But meaning of the word has changed with time as I point out.

Comment: Famous quote: "*Freedom's just another word for 'nothing left to lose'.*" So, only people with no attachments are free.

Comment: @ScottRowe I find this quote interesting and contrary to my personal beliefs related to Mahayana. Do you by any chance practice Hinayana Buddhism?

Comment: I did study and practice in the Self Realization tradition for a long time. I thought of Hinayana as less helpful than Mahayana, but I am more aligned with Advaita Vedanta, I think. Nonduality, anyway.

Comment: I was thinking of saying something similar to @ScottRowe : Ramana Maharshi (renowned advaita teacher) : «Bondage is the thought "I am the body". Mukti (freedom) is getting rid of that thought»

Comment: @Rusi-packing-up Yes, basically identifying oneself with anything, including oneself or any aspect of it is a problem. But due to the way almost all people routinely cognize, they can't really understand. It takes a breakthrough of experience to change the perspective. Knowledge that can't be taught but which could greatly improve humanity is kind of awkward. The movies "Arrival" and "LUCY" are good pointers.

Comment: I like the following "definition" of freedom : "Freedom is being master of oneself", this directly opens up various degrees of freedom which can be linked up to existentialism and beyond.

Comment: @NikosM. Thanks I like the ring of that.

Comment: @NikosM. For small values of 'oneself'.

Comment: @ScottRowe I can't seem to comprehend how: "I am the master of my fate,
      I am the captain of my soul" amounts small values of 'oneself'

Comment: As one comes to grips with what one actually 'is', there is not a whole lot there. The only enduring aspects are agency and ongoing experience. So, "*I am the master of my fate*" seems like a tautology. Like, " you and everyone else ".

Comment: @ScottRowe One could argue for an even 'smaller' value of self, one where even agency and experience are left outside.  The non duality teacher Ramana would repeatedly draw attention to this: *You exist in deep sleep. The proof of that is the abiding sense of happiness that remains over. Yet no agency, experience. Or even time space.* Slightly expanded at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/65146/37256

Comment: @Rusi-packing-up Samadhi?

Comment: @ScottRowe continuing at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/65146/37256 where this discussion is more relevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very well thought-out question. You invoke Noam Chomsky's contributions to the philosophy of mind with his proposals regarding innate properties which he puts forward in his ideas regarding [universal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_grammar). You also bring to the conversation an awareness of the contributions of later LW regarding his arguments about philosophy of language that contributed to the [linguistic turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_turn). Among the [analytic tribes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy), it is now part of the philosophical method to explicitly examine language to suss out what is about reality, and what is about language. The erstwhile [Sapir-Whorf hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity) is part of such a discussion.

> I find myself asking is it possible to coherently hold onto [a] set of insights?

There seems to be two questions implicit in your question. 1. Is it possible for anyone to hold on to contradictory notions? 2. Are the following notions contradictory?

The answers in short order are yes, and depends.

First, obviously the psychology of dealing with logic and contradiction is addressed by Festinger's [cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance), and it's a matter of psychological fact that the brain is capable of not seeing logical contradictions. In extreme pathologies of the mind, the philosopher of the mind of a [naturalized epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalized_epistemology) must accept that the rules of logic are subject to psychological truths. To buttress this fact, the current state of logics is one of [metaphysical pluralism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralism_(philosophy)#Metaphysical_pluralism). [Dialetheia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetheism), to which contradiction inheres and is accepted, is a perfectly legitimate metaphysical position. So, I push back and ask, is logical coherence and the [coherent theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_theory_of_truth) really so weighty matter that it can be applied in such a wide-ranging examination of [propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition)? [Worldviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldview), to be succinct, are not mathematical theorems.

Second, if you do attempt to play the philosophical game of trying to get the [truth-conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-conditional_semantics) of claims to align like a [mathematical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) to show that you can refute any claims of contradiction, are you cognizant of the fact that both ambiguity and vagueness may inhere so much in [natural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language), that absent experience, you may not be able to pin down definitions, which are notoriously complicated affairs, to do so? LW's [family resemblances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_resemblance), which has laid the ground work in linguistics for [prototype theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_theory), challenges us to accept that natural language definitions for words like 'freedom' and 'neoliberalism' are tricky affairs. In fact, such efforts beg the question if it's possible to even pin down a concept? Definitions are without a doubt (and not to sound like a critical theorist), political matters. What does freedom mean after all? On the gates of Auschwitz was placed for all to see "Arbeit macht frei". Work is freedom. Words are susceptible to abuse by propaganda in the extreme, but even every day, the meaning of words are contested. Enter Gallie's thesis: some words are [essentially contested concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essentially_contested_concept).

Can you make those 5 claims cohere? Absolutely. Terms like 'freedom' are so flexible that anyone can use them to mean just about anything they'd like. Many a sophist has made a buck waxing philosophical on semantic nuance.

> Could Wittgenstien or anyone even define freedom?

Who doesn't have a definition of freedom? Definitions are like anuses. Everyone has one. The actual challenge is shopping for the definition that suits you and your experience. For some, there's freedom in bondage. For others, it's a religious devotion to libertarianism even if it enslaves them financially. Suicide is arguably finding freedom from life. The real error here may be in presuming that definitions have some objective reality and correctness as opposed to understanding them as acts of [social construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_constructivism). After all, LW's [private language argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_language_argument) highlights the highly [normative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativity) grounding of definitions to begin with.

Comment: @J D if you don't mind me asking how do you function in a neo-liberal democracy? I find too much (ironically using the word) freedom in your answer. In the sense I can could read this answer and basically say based on these set of ideas I shall operate in X, Y, Z, L, M manner. Also since this is a bit personal I won't mind if you ignore this comment :)

Comment: Not ironically. The freedom that inheres in the relativism of my response is part and parcel of the freedom we are all afforded by pursuing our Authentic self, to borrow from the Existentialists. In fact, I'm arguably an absurdist, in that I divest myself of grand, sweeping normative claims. We are born, we live, and we die. You can construct a catgorical imperative, like Kant, to attempt to subsume the minutiae of your day-to-day, but simply embrace a situational ethics, and recognize the inherent normativity of the human condition and your embodiment...

Comment: and that is freedom from the tyranny of analysis. Follow the Golden rule, but adhere to the observation that we have a moral imperative to be imperative. Accept that we are biological computers whose worldview is a fallibilistic model of the physical... observe that people play language games, and that politics is inevitable....

Comment: figure out who you are, and be your best self. Live, labor, laugh, and love. Why make it more complicated? Do what you have to do, and accept your limits, not the least of which is that you only have so much control. What more is there?

Comment: If you are interested in philosophy, just remember that all linguistic categories begin with dichotomy, and that all dichotomy is nothing more than the imposition of linguistic category on physical experience. The rest follows.

Comment: And there's nothing wrong with questions about eudaimonia!

Comment: *moral imperative to be intelligent

Comment: Max Tegmark said, "*Intelligence is the ability to accomplish goals.*" This lines up with my sense that agency is the most crucial thing.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia - [Neoliberalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoliberalism), or neo-liberalism, "is a term used to describe the 20th-century resurgence of 19th-century ideas associated with free-market capitalism."

In contrast, how about *liberalism*? and individual freedom of thought in relation to the group, from a review of [Group Psychology and Political Theory](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Group+Psychology+and+Political+Theory.-a018540210):

> [Alford calls] for a much closer and sympathetic look not only at
> leadership but at the group foundations of political life. The group,
> in his view, precedes the individual; and it makes no sense to speak
> of social or political experience unless it is understood in the
> context of groups. The greatest efforts in establishing individuality
> lie in the often tragic process of freeing oneself from group
> domination and control; his political argument here clearly comes down
> on the side of ***liberal individualism*** and against the constraining,
> often authoritarian, demands of "community."
>
> We literally, Alford argues, are at war with our own "groupishness";
> and this is what gets us into personal and political trouble. He calls
> this process the "schizoid compromise ... the fundamental
> psychological event in the groups . . . the member tries to have his
> cake and eat it too: to give himself over to the group, while being
> separate and independent of it" (p. 52).

Chulhan's suggestion "that we are projects to be worked on” would seems quite enlightened, except for then saying this "is really just a more efficient form of subjugation".  I don't think individuation can be passed off as a synthetic trend.

Comment: Hey. Please think of my questions as a means for me to understand. If I understand you argue Byung Chulhan's critique holds for liberalism as well? I suspect, you deny point 5: "I don't think individuation can be passed off as a synthetic trend" (it would be helpful if you told why?) Also "individual freedom of thought in relation to the group" seems like "idea of self-realization through others." no?

Comment: Re. point 5, I would say freedom and [liberalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalism) are not at odds.  (Without meaning [American political liberalism](https://www.sparknotes.com/us-government-and-politics/political-science/political-ideologies-and-styles/section4/).)

Comment: I don't see "The greatest efforts in establishing individuality lie in the often tragic process of freeing oneself from group domination and control; his political argument here clearly comes down on the side of liberal individualism and against the constraining" and  "idea of self-realization through others" necessarily at odds with each other. What am I missing?

Comment: For example, you can learn and discuss philosophy with others, but when you arrive at certain ideas you may find (parts of) the group might not agree with them.

Comment: So you question "Freedom is to be among friends to have a successful relationship"? and the common basis for the friendship is the creed? I wouldn't even consider such people friends to begin with. But that's me. Thanks I think I get what you were getting at.

Comment: We have to individuate from ourselves too. George Bush said, "*I have opinions,* strong opinions, *but I don't always agree with them.*"