# What exactly is duality?

Tags: taoism, saussure

As a novice in philosophy, I haven't read all the material available on the subject of *duality* but I find it fascinating for both its profound simplicity and for being responsible for my brain telling me THIS DOES NOT COMPUTE whenever I attempt to process it.

Anyway, here's what I know ...

Heraclitus, the weeping philosopher, is said to have viewed the world as a *harmony of **opposites***; Empedocles, another Greek philosopher who allegedly threw himself into a volcano, built his philosophy on *love* and *strife* (two *opposing forces* as it were).

Now let's travel east, the mysterious orient and we meet Laozi, the founder of Taosim. This ancient Chinese philosophy has exactly the same idea - opposites in equilibrium (yin-yang).

What is it that Heraclitus, Empedocles, and Laozi are talking about. In the simplest sense, *pairs* such as hot-cold, light-dark, man-woman, love-hate, you get the idea. So far so good.

We now journey to Hindoostan aka India and there we encounter *advaita* (no two) i.e. *non-duality* or *unity*.

The floor is open for all. Please ...

1. Comment
2. Correct
3. Cite resources
4. Etc.

and help me deepen my understanding of *dvaita*.

Merci beaucoup mes amies.

Comment: Yes, [Binary opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_opposition) is, according to some school of thought, a key feature of human mind/language/culture/society. See also [Yin and yang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang) as well as [Daoism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/daoism/#Intro)

Comment: Maybe useful GER Lloyd, [Polarity and Analogy](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Polarity_and_Analogy/a8hhGVIOCDIC) as well as R. Hertz, [Death and the right hand](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Death_and_the_right_hand/DVxGAQAAQBAJ).

Comment: It is curious that the tag is to Taoism, but the examples are not.

Comment: Gracias for the comments & links.

Comment: You don't have to throw yourself in to a volcano, just stick with Nonduality, like your brain says.

Comment: My current favorite resource for non-duality:  [Rupert Spira: You Are the Happiness You Seek](https://www.amazon.com/You-Are-Happiness-Seek-Uncovering/dp/1684030129)

Comment: "The floor is open for all." That floor is someone else's ceiling. Duality!

Comment: Duality is neither one thing nor the other.

Comment: Much obliged for all the comments. @user4894, care to expand & elaborate on what you said?

Comment: @BobaFit, what do you mean? Duality is neither A nor B?

Comment: @ScottRowe, I wish I could - I'm kinda being pulled apart (drawn & quartered?). I encounter duality every single day, but me mind experiences *akatalepsis* when I try to, well, hold the idea in my mind, figuratively speaking.

Comment: You may find it useful to meditate on the advaitic phrase: *The happiness of deep sleep where there is no mind.* More [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/65146/37256)

Comment: @Rusi-packing-up. That's an intriguing statement, but why is everyone so obsessed about *waking up*?

Comment: A good question @AgentSmith. An advaitist like Ramana Maharshi would say we desire *the consciousness of waking plus the happiness of deep sleep*.  In trying to get above the rest aka smart aka conscious-er than others *we've forgotten the supreme desirability of 'happiness of deep sleep where there is no mind' so no others ie Advaita*. It's weird but we all become one in deep sleep, just that we don't know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with the concept of *is/isn't*. The human mind tends to objectify. We identify an object *as* an object and separate it (mentally) from the background. In other words, we walk into a room and our minds automatically snap things into focus: *this* is a chair, *that* is a table, the room is warm, everything else is not-chair, not-table, not-warm. This objectification isn't essential — an intelligent squid-like alien from Europa would not necessarily pick out a table and chair as objects, or appreciate the concept of warmth — but it is such an automatic and engrained response that we think of these things as 'ontologically real'.

But that isn't the case. Imagine, for instance, walking through the woods and finding a flat tree-stump. You can sit on it, so it might be a chair; you can put stuff on it, so it might be a table; you can admire it as an old tree stump; you can trip over it (making it a mere obstacle) or ignore it as part of the seamless natural background... It is what it is (in some trivial way), but it is also what we make of it, and it is **also** *not* what we *don't* make of it.

Whatever our mind constitutes as a 'thing' is necessarily separated from and opposed to everything that is not that thing. That is the act of objectification. We see a yellow patch in the sky and we say "that is the sun", but we only know it's the sun because there is a lot of sky that isn't yellow. If the entire sky were uniform yellow, we wouldn't have a sun.

The world itself is a continuity. Mountaintops and valley floors are nothing more than a momentary balance among competing forces, subject to ongoing change. Intelligent beings (humans) separate mountaintops from valley floors and think the mountaintops will always be mountaintops and the valleys will always be valleys, because they think of them as separate objects. The intelligent mind tries to create monads — single objects that exist without reference to anything else — but that merely creates the *is/isn't* duality out of the continuity of what is.

Comment: Zen saying: "*In the beginning, mountains are mountains and rivers are rivers; later on, mountains are not mountains and rivers are not rivers; and still later, mountains are mountains and rivers are rivers.*" That middle part is what is interesting.

Comment: True, what *is* doesn't make sense without what *isn't*. There's got to be, to use a photographic term, *contrast* - something of interest (say x) has to stand out from the rest. My simple question (to all) is, what's the rationale for, in some cases, wanting to do away with one half of a given duality e.g. we all want a good education as opposed to a bad one? Gracias in advance.

Comment: @AgentSmith: daodejing 77: "The dao is like the bending of a bow. What is high up is pulled down, what is low down is lifted up; what has surplus is reduced, what is deficient is supplemented. The way of heaven reduces those who have surpluses to supplement those who are deficient. The way of man is different: It reduces those who are deficient to offer to those who have surpluses." People want to be rid of dualities because duality entails continuity so that excesses are always ultimately reduced.

Comment: @AgentSmith:  People (err... unwise people) only want more, and reject the prospect of less. The idea of duality implies opposition and threat; the idea of continuity implies responsibility and acceptance. Any unenlightened person would (metaphorically speaking) cut off half his face if doing so would give the other half eternal youth and beauty. It is the nature of craving to rot the heart of the one who craves.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley. Nice! You completed the picture as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @AgentSmith Quote from The Dancing Wu Li Masters: "That which is, is that which is. That which is not, is that which is." Zero depends on where you put it in your value scale: at the bottom, the middle, the top... But it is always a continuous scale.

Comment: The force is strong with this one! I sense *mathematics* in there somewhere. It remains to be seen though, at least for me, whether what we're dealing with is *satya* or *maya*.

Comment: @AgentSmith A common saying is "samsara is nirvana", so you don't need to give up anything.

Comment: That is an interesting expression.

Answer (score 2):

A very partial answer:

In physics a duality is a pair of dissimilar sets (e.g. particles, probability waves) with one-to-one correspondence (e.g. *this* particle **corresponds to** *this* probability wave) on which an analogous operation (these two particles *composited* together **is analogous to** these two waves *composited* together) generates one-to-one correspondence of the resulting set element (this *system of two particles* **corresponds to** this *superposition of waves*).

Since physics is the application of formal logic to a logical universe, this narrow definition may be of some use in philosophy.

Comment: So we could simply say that mind and matter *correspond*. Problem solved!

Comment: I suppose *dissimilar* is the word of interest. A correspondence between what an object is in one model to what an object is in another model?

Comment: @ScottRowe I would say that the mind (the emergent phenomenon) and the physical processes of the CNS (which might be called "matter" in a non-physics sense) might correspond in this way, although one could make an argument that mind is a subset of the "matter", not a separate set.

Comment: @AgentSmith To be strictly correct: between what mathematical object takes as a particular set of related measurements as eigenvalues in one model vs in another. Strictly speaking, physics doesn't deal in physical objects, only abstract logical objects and measurements.

Comment: The mathematical object and the rules that it follows are the model, the model either predicts future measurements on the basis of past measurements and is a good model, or it doesn't and is a bad model, and the theory (if you have one) is that there is a physical object in the real universe that behaves like the mathematical model.

Comment: @g s . That's really interesting to say the least. A scientific perspective on consciousness is refreshingly pragmatic. Gracias.

Comment: It's funny that this definition of duality is mentioned, because it is actually a narrow specialization of a much more general concept in mathematics: duality and the Lagrangian. I'll see if I can post an answer that discusses this in a bit more detail.

Comment: @ldog Cool. Sounds like the normal relationship between physics and mathematics! I will follow and look forward to your discussion.

Comment: Indeed, [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)) is a widely used concept in math, so general that it's hard to explain. The Wikipedia page gives many examples that may, even to the uninitiated, provide some sense of it, but as usual with very general mathematical concepts it's something where understanding usually doesn't come until you've made use of it in several different situations from which an intuition for the generality of it slowly develops.

Comment: That said, it doesn't seem to relate to the example given in the original question, which seems more to be developing the kinds of things to which you might be able to _apply_ a duality. Love versus strife, for example, might be seen as a function on a set of things that when applied to any one thing evaluates to "is love" or "is strife" (and perhaps "is neither" or even "is both.") A duality of that might be a "parallel mapping" of a different function on to a different set of things that has some correspondence, in its inputs and answers, to the function described above.

Comment: @gs, The word "dissimilar", does it mean *mutually exclusive* like for instance the *wave-particle duality* (electrons behaving like waves sometimes and like particles other times)?

Comment: @AgentSmith Yes to the colloquial sense. I don't know about formally. I'm not sure whether exclusivity is a necessary or sufficient condition in mathematics. I'd be worried about accidentally labeling as dualities things that aren't dualities in a sense useful to philosophy, like sets that are transformations of each other or any two sets with 0 or 1 element. Physics SE or Mathematics SE might have useful answers to this line of inquiry if you mention that your interest is applying formal logic to real life phenomena that are often informally identified as having the nature of duality.

Comment: You said physics treats physical objects as mathematical ones, what would be a mathematical interpretation of duality? +x & -x? Does, for example, mass and volume constitute a mathematical duality?

Comment: @AgentSmith I've never heard of anyone referring to things like that as dualities, nor do I think they would fit the definition. A liter corresponds to a kilogram when it's underwater at room temperature, but in outer space a liter does not. We can map kilograms of water at room temperature to liters of water at room temperature, but doing so is just defining one unit in terms of the other unit: kg = L * (density of water).

Comment: @gs Danke. I think that's about as much as I can handle right now. Good day.